# grepl in R: Replace character/numeric levels

Tags: r, grepl, levels

I've like to replace my levels dog1 ... dog4 and cat1 ... cat4 by only two levels DOG and CAT, but if I use grepl my output as only NAs.

In my code:

```
x  <- (rep(c("dog1","dog2","dog3","dog4","cat1","cat2","cat3","cat4"),2)) #Levels
y<-rnorm(16)
d<-data.frame(cbind(x,y))
head(d)

     x                 y
1 dog1 0.906357739138289
2 dog2 0.974674552504268
3 dog3 0.664045049199848
4 dog4 0.911777985232099
5 cat1 0.246575548162824
6 cat2 0.758069789161901


d$x[grepl("dog", d$x)] <- "DOG"
```

> Warning message: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, grepl("dog", d$x), value =
>   c(NA, NA, NA,  :   invalid factor level, NA generated

```
d$x[grepl("cat", d$x)] <- "CAT"

Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, grepl("cat", d$x), value = c(NA_integer_,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

head(d)

     x                 y
1 <NA> 0.906357739138289
2 <NA> 0.974674552504268
3 <NA> 0.664045049199848
4 <NA> 0.911777985232099
5 <NA> 0.246575548162824
6 <NA> 0.758069789161901
```

My desirable output if the code run OK is:

```
head(d)

     x                 y
1 DOG  0.906357739138289
2 DOG  0.974674552504268
3 DOG  0.664045049199848
4 DOG  0.911777985232099
5 CAT  0.246575548162824
6 CAT  0.758069789161901
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try creating the data frame with strings as factors false:

```
d <- data.frame(cbind(x,y), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
d$x[grepl("dog", d$x)] <- "DOG"
d$x[grepl("cat", d$x)] <- "CAT"
```

Answer (score 1):

Key here (as Tim has hinted) is understanding how `factor` variables, while similar on the surface, are actually completely different from `character` variables.

Here is one way to access and update the levels of your factor:

```
levels(d$x)
# [1] "cat1" "cat2" "cat3" "cat4" "dog1" "dog2" "dog3" "dog4"

levels(d$x)[grepl("dog", levels(d$x))] <- "DOG"
levels(d$x)[grepl("cat", levels(d$x))] <- "CAT"
head(d)
#     x                   y
# 1 DOG -0.0489713202962167
# 2 DOG  -0.548503649991368
# 3 DOG   0.460493884654479
# 4 DOG   0.143044665735075
# 5 CAT   -2.13008189672678
# 6 CAT  -0.136767747543626

levels(d$x)
[1] "CAT" "DOG"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another version but using regex here. We capture everything until a digit is found and turn it to upper case. (`\\U`).

```
d$x <- sub("(.*)\\d+", "\\U\\1", d$x, perl = TRUE)
d$x
 #[1] "DOG" "DOG" "DOG" "DOG" "CAT" "CAT" "CAT" "CAT" "DOG" "DOG" "DOG" "DOG" 
 #    "CAT" "CAT" "CAT" "CAT"
```